# How to fix ‘memory leak’ in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a C program a dynamically allocated

Can someone please explain how to fix this memory leak in "goto"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("start main\n");
    char *f = NULL;
    L1:
        f = (char *)malloc(10);
        if (f == NULL)
            return -1;
        printf("body lebel\n");
        f = "A";
        if (f == "B") {
            free(f);
            goto L1;
        }

      return 0;

 return 0;
}
```

`valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out`,

Output:

```
==7217== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7217==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==7217==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,034 bytes 
allocated
```

Comment: Move `free` to right after `printf`, before assignment and consequent leak.

Comment: `f = "A"` - do you understand what happens here?

Comment: There are a few valid uses of `goto`. As a loop is not one of them.

Comment: What's the point of `if (f == "B")` ? This condifion is always false, even if the rest of your code was correct.

Comment: To summarize: It seems you could use a beginners book or two to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
f = "A";
```

assigns the char pointer `f` to point to `"A"`, which is a `const char*` that lives somewhere in the process image.  This completely orphans the memory you allocated with `malloc`.  To copy the string `"A"` to the memory that `f` points to, you need to write something like

```
strcpy(f, "A");
```

or

```
strncpy(f, "A", 10);
```

with the caveat that `strcpy` might overrun the buffer you have allocated for `f` and `strncpy` might leave it non-null-terminated.

Second, you only free `f` inside of the if statement before you jump to `L1`.  To free `f` before the program exits as well, you also have to write `free(f)` before `return 0`.

Third, `f == "B"` checks whether `f` points to the const char* value `"B"`, not whether its contents are the same as `"B"`.  In your program, this is always false since you assign it to `"A"` just before you compare it.  You need to use function like `strcmp` for null-terminated strings or `memcmp` for possibly non-null-terminated strings.

It would also be possible to move the first `free` to the beginning of the label, so that you don't have to make sure that you free it before jumping, since `free(NULL)` does not do anything.  Also in the interest of posterity you should declare `"A"` and `"B"` as variables and move the constant `10` into a variable as well to help prevent memory violations in the future:

```
int main()
{
    const char a_str[] = "A";
    const char b_str[] = "B";
    size_t buffer_size = 10;
    printf("start main\n");
    char *f = NULL;
    L1:
        free(f);
        f = (char *)malloc(buffer_size);
        if (f == NULL)
            return -1;
        printf("body lebel\n");
        if (buffer_size < sizeof(a_str)) {
            printf("Buffer too small for %s\n", a_str);
            exit(1);
        }
        memcpy(f, a_str, sizeof(a_str));
        if (buffer_size < sizeof(b_str)) {
            printf("Buffer too small for comparison with %s\n", b_str);
            exit(1);
        }
        if (!memcmp(f, b_str, sizeof(b_str)) {
            goto L1;
        }
    free(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should mention that `goto` is being abused here.

Comment: move 1st `free` to inside `if (!strcmp(f, "B"))` block. With that you don't need to call `free(NULL)` and it is more readable.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 you should mention that `!strcmp(f, "B")` is always true.

Comment: @kiranBiradar IMHO it's more readable this way.  It also makes the diffs smaller if you move the `if` block.

Comment: `free` before `malloc` is always wrong, reader will be at toss.

Comment: @kiranBiradar not necessarily, `free(NULL)` is OK, but I agree, it's awkward, but anyway, the whole code is pretty pointless anyway and the abuse of goto is appalling.

Comment: hey, you have to pick your battles